# Prestashop, Smarty template renders too many buttons

Tags: templates, smarty, prestashop

I've got this code in my prestashop template, there is no loop, only conditional, and I get 5 back buttons (elseif section, first li tag), why is it happen?

```
{if $node.children|@count > 0 && ($smarty.get.controller!='product' && $smarty.get.controller!='category')}

    <li class = "li-parent">
    <asset class="menu-arrow-left"></asset>
    <p><span><a href="{$node.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$node.desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p>


{elseif $node.children|@count > 0 && ($smarty.get.controller=='product' || $smarty.get.controller=='category')}

    <li class="li-back"><asset class="menu-arrow-right"></asset><p class="class="border-bottom-grandiet-small"><span>Back</span></p></li>
    <li class = "li-parent">
    <p><span><a href="{$node.children[0].link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$node.desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.children[0].name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p>

{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in this code that could cause displaying 5 back buttons. I suspect this code is included in some kind of loop and that's why it's displayed 5 times.

You should change the whole above code with:

```
testonly
```

and then look at page or page source and check how many `testonly` texts will appear.

It's also possible if you really use loop that you should use some extra condition. For example instead of:

```
<li class="li-back"><asset class="menu-arrow-right"></asset><p class="class="border-bottom-grandiet-small"><span>Back</span></p></li>
```

you should use

```
{if $node.children|@iteration eq 1} 
<li class="li-back"><asset class="menu-arrow-right"></asset><p class="class="border-bottom-grandiet-small"><span>Back</span></p></li>
{/if}
```

and probably the rest should be more similar to the first condition so instead of:

```
<li class = "li-parent">
    <p><span><a href="{$node.children[0].link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$node.desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.children[0].name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p>
```

you should use:

```
<li class = "li-parent">
    <p><span><a href="{$node.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$node.desc|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></span></p>
```

but it's really hard to say if we don't know what's the data structure and what exactly you want to achieve. If it still doesn't work you should provide more details to your question, explain what you want to achieve, what data you have in your variables and so on.

Comment: Still the same, testonly appears 5 times, but for example links in tags don't repeat.

Comment: It didn't work but I'll try to fix it and if  I'll figure it out, I'll let you know. Thanks for your help.